# Alternative for concat

Tags: python, date, pandas

I combine the same table as follows:

```
   pd.concat([df_dates,
               df_dates,
               df_dates,
               df_dates]
```

how to write the code more briefly

Comment: I don't know what `pd.concat` does, but `[df_dates, df_dates, df_dates, df_dates]` can just be written `[df_dates]*4`

Comment: You can do `pd.concat([df_dates]*4])` but what are you after here, this is shorter code but it's not speed efficient, for instance `pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df_dates), 4, columns = df_dates.columns)` will be faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're after in terms of efficiency but here are 2 methods:

```
In [32]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,2), columns=list('ab'))
df

Out[32]:
          a         b
0  0.108453 -2.875348
1 -1.502857  0.057709
2  0.356384 -0.870802
```

You can just repeat the df in a list:

```
In [33]:    
pd.concat([df]*4)

Out[33]:
          a         b
0  0.108453 -2.875348
1 -1.502857  0.057709
2  0.356384 -0.870802
0  0.108453 -2.875348
1 -1.502857  0.057709
2  0.356384 -0.870802
0  0.108453 -2.875348
1 -1.502857  0.057709
2  0.356384 -0.870802
0  0.108453 -2.875348
1 -1.502857  0.057709
2  0.356384 -0.870802
```

but it will quicker to use [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and repeat the df:

```
In [56]:
pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df,(4,1)), columns= df.columns)

Out[56]:
           a         b
0   0.108453 -2.875348
1  -1.502857  0.057709
2   0.356384 -0.870802
3   0.108453 -2.875348
4  -1.502857  0.057709
5   0.356384 -0.870802
6   0.108453 -2.875348
7  -1.502857  0.057709
8   0.356384 -0.870802
9   0.108453 -2.875348
10 -1.502857  0.057709
11  0.356384 -0.870802
```

**timings**

```
In [57]:
%timeit pd.concat([df]*4)
%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df,(4,1)), columns= df.columns)

1000 loops, best of 3: 621 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 142 µs per loop
```

Here you can see that even on this small dataset the numpy method is over 4x times quicker and will scale much better for large datasets especially when you increase the repeat number:

```
In [65]:
%timeit pd.concat([df]*400)
%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df,(400,1)), columns= df.columns)

10 loops, best of 3: 37.5 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 152 µs per loop
```

Here for 400 repeats we see that numpy is ~300 x faster

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Jeff for pointing this out, if your df has mixed dtypes (in terms of across the df, not for a particular column) then the dtypes will be munged:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(3),'b':np.arange(3)})
df

Out[2]:
          a  b
0 -0.016903  0
1  1.440656  1
2 -1.073728  2

In [3]:
pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df,(4,1)), columns= df.columns)

Out[3]:
           a    b
0  -0.016903  0.0
1   1.440656  1.0
2  -1.073728  2.0
3  -0.016903  0.0
4   1.440656  1.0
5  -1.073728  2.0
6  -0.016903  0.0
7   1.440656  1.0
8  -1.073728  2.0
9  -0.016903  0.0
10  1.440656  1.0
11 -1.073728  2.0
```

Here the `int64` dtype for column 'b' has now been converted to `float64` which is not desirable here

Comment: need to be really careful about doing things like this: numpy methods generally munge dtypes together only to be re-inferred when you recreate the frame. so this would not generally be recommended

Comment: @Jeff presumably this would be safe so long as the dtypes were pandas friendly and homogenous? I'll add an update to my answer to mention, thanks for the information

Comment: @Jeff thanks I just posted a simple example that demonstrates this

Answer (score 2):

You could use
`pd.concat([df_dates] * 4)`

As you might guess, the `*4` uses that element 4 times.